# How does the compiler allocate memory for an array of strings in C?

Tags: c

I typed up this block of code for an assignment:

```
char *tokens[10];

void parse(char* input);

void main(void) 
{
    char input[] = "Parse this please.";
    parse(input);

    for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%s ", tokens[i]);
    }
}

void parse(char* input)
{
    int i = 0;
    tokens[i] = strtok(input, " ");

    while(tokens[i] != NULL) {
        i++;
        tokens[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

But, looking at it, I'm not sure how the memory allocation works. I didn't define the length of the individual strings as far as I know, just how many strings are in the string array tokens (10). Do I have this backwards? If not, then is the compiler allocating the length of each string dynamically? In need of some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok` is a bad citizen.

For one thing, it retains state, as you've implicitly used when you call `strtok(NULL,...)` -- this state is stored in the private memory of the Standard C Library, which means only single threaded programs can use `strtok`. Note that there is a reentrant version called `strtok_r` in some libraries.

For another, and to answer your question, `strtok` modifies its input. It doesn't allocate space for the strings; it writes NUL characters in place of your delimiter in the input string, and returns a pointer into the input string.

You are correct that `strtok` can return more than 10 results. You should check for that in your code so you don't write beyond the end of `tokens`. A reliable program would either set an upper limit, like your `10`, and check for it, reporting an error if it's exceeded, or dynamically allocate the `tokens` array with `malloc`, and `realloc` it if it gets too big. Then the error occurs when you fun out of memory.

Note that you can also work around the problem of `strtok` modifying your input string by `strdup`ing before passing it to `strtok`. Then you'll have to free the new string after both it and `tokens`, which points to it, are going out of scope.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, that's good to know. So, I was thinking about it wrong. `tokens` is not a 2 dimensional array of chars, but an array of pointers. So the compiler allocates for sizeof(void *) not for multiple characters.

Comment: @Doug Currie It should be noted that strdup is not a standard C library function, and is likely not available on platforms that are not POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 1):

`tokens` is an array of pointers.

The distinction between strings and pointers if often fuzzy. In some situations strings are better thought out as arrays, in other situations as pointers.

Anyway... in your example `input` is an array and `tokens` is an array of pointers to a place within `input`.

The data inside `input` is changed with each call to `strtok()`

So, step by step

```
// input[] = "foo bar baz";
tokens[0] = strtok(input, " ");
// input[] = "foo\0bar baz";
//            ^-- tokens[0] points here
tokens[1] = strtok(NULL, " ");
// input[] = "foo\0bar\0baz";
//                 ^-- tokens[1] points here
tokens[2] = strtok(NULL, " ");
// input[] = "foo\0bar\0baz";
//                      ^-- tokens[2] points here
// next strtok returns NULL
```